# Flutter RawKeyboardListener and External Bluetooth scanner

Tags: android, ios, flutter, barcode

I'm trying to get the data of an external bluetooth scanner withour using a TextField. I tried to use RawKeyboardListener but this doesn't seem to work.

I'm testing the solution on an Ipad with a code based on that solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/dev/manual_tests/lib/raw_keyboard.dart

Is it the right path to get to a solution or have you got another way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Did you find any fix?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular KeyboardListener.

```
KeyboardListener(
    focusNode: node,
    onKeyEvent: (value) {
      if (value.runtimeType == KeyDownEvent) {
```